# sklearn validation score meaning

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Whenever i train an MLP model on sklearn, I get this output here:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier


clf_mlp = MLPClassifier(random_state=1,\
                        max_iter=200,\
                        hidden_layer_sizes=(256,256,256),\
                        early_stopping = True,\
                        verbose=True).fit(X, pdf_train["label"])
```

```
Iteration 1, loss = 1.23744239
Validation score: 0.649914
Iteration 2, loss = 1.07239263
Validation score: 0.652249
Iteration 3, loss = 0.99360697
Validation score: 0.652205
Iteration 4, loss = 0.90097632
Validation score: 0.646963
<And it goes on...>
```

I`m confused about how to read this log: Is the "loss" there a Training Loss or Validation loss? And is the "Validation score" value accuracy or is it validation loss?

If you could point where in sklearn documentation this is explained, I would be grateful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `loss` that is printed is the *training* loss (default: log-loss) as evidenced by [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L549).

The `Validation score` that is printed is indeed the score (default: accuracy) on the validation data, as evidenced by [this function in the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L594).

This should definitely be better documented, feel free to [submit an issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues).

Answer (score 2):

The loss is calculated on the training set ([see here in source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf39bbdacd6ed713c00724f8f871d60370/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L544)). The validation score is the accuracy on the validation set. The score function is defined from sklearn's base [ClassifierMixin](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin.html).